# how can i solve the system.invalidcastexception

Tags: c#

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection sqlcon1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=PRATHISTA;Initial Catalog=CRMT;Integrated Security=True");
    sqlcon1.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("select * from Requirement", sqlcon1);
    try
    {
        SqlDataReader sda1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        while (sda1.Read())
        {
            string sId = sda1.GetString("Requirement_Id");
            // i get the error here;
        }
        sda1.Close();
        sqlcon1.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error:" + ex);

    }
}
```

Comment: It seems that `Requirement_Id` is `int`, not `string`. Try `int id = sda1.GetInt32("Requirement_Id")`.

Comment: If `sda1.GetString("Requirement_Id")1 null then check `!SqlReader.IsDBNull("Requirement_Id")` before assigning.

Comment: Can you please add the datatypes of your table columns? Probably `Requirement_Id` is not a string.

Comment: and **No conversions are performed in GetString; therefore, the data retrieved must already be a string.**, else use other suitable interface like GetInt32 suggested by  @MarkShevchenko

Answer (score 0):

As your id column isn't a string, the database doesn't return a string - you can only use the `GetString` method for string columns. You now have two options:

1. Using `GetInt32`
2. Directly getting the data from the reader

The first option is done like that:

```
var sId = sda1.GetInt32(index);
```

Remember however that the index here can't be of type string and must be an integer.

The second option is better (in my opinion) in that case:

```
var sId = (int)sda1["Requirement_Id"];
```

You can (of course) still use a string:

```
var sId = sda1["Requirement_Id"].ToString();
```